# How to remove the space between html buttons?

Tags: html, css

I don't know those spaces got there and how to remove them. Any help would be aprreciated

```css
.square{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#FF9500;
    color:#000;
    font-size:50px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div id="allbuttons">
    <div class="line">
        <button class = "square" id="b1">1</button>
        <button class = "square" id="b2">2</button>
        <button class="square" id="b3">3</button>  
    </div>
    <div class="line" >
        <button class = "square" id="b4">4</button>
        <button class = "square" id="b5">5</button>
        <button class="square" id="b6">6</button>  
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <button class = "square" id="b7">7</button>
        <button class = "square" id="b8">8</button>
        <button class="square" id="b9">9</button>  
    </div>
    </div>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZg9Z.png)

Comment: Get rid of the white space in between the ```div``` elements

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: Instead of ```</div>``` return tab and then ```<div class="line">```, you need to delete the space in between the ```<div>``` elements.  Example: ```</div><div class="line">```

Comment: https://codepen.io/sethblackwater/pen/jOOeWBz

Comment: I took all white space out, and it works now.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!